# Many errors after trying to set facebook-sdk in android studio

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have 2 issues. First, I added the facebook sdk, and after that, many errors appeared.
The same but repetitive errors in my java 'main file' is 'cannot resolve symbol' in the R and all others.

second issue, the following error:

> "diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6" , "Execution failed for task ':facebook:compileReleaseJava'. > compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."
>   (and that's after doing everything just like in the tutorials)

thanks in advance! I'm stuck in this like for about 3 weeks and almost everyday I tried solving but I still can't figure out a way.
grade:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.noy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.noy.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thanks

Comment: please show the gradle file and manifest file

Comment: Please add the project's build.gradle file

Comment: the build.gradle is the first quote...

Comment: please add error logcat screenshot.

Comment: this is your module level gradle file.There will be another file Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects.Check you have both repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    } if you are using maven

Comment: how do i get to the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the use of the library by calling

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

in your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

1)Include in your apps settings.gradle

like this:

```
include ':facebookSDKVersion_3141'
```

2)You have to compile your facebook sdk in your apps build.gradle
do like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':facebookSDKVersion_3141') 
}
```

Clean the project and build the project again should work.

or

There is an easier way ,click on file on android studio
select New Module->Import Existing Project->Browse the location of your sdk

and this should work

Comment: 1. should I replace it with include ':app', ':facebook'?

Comment: Is that your settings.gradle or build.gradle ?

Comment: about 2, do i have to go to 'project' and click build.guild and put this: compile project(':facebookSDKVersion_3141') into dependencies, after this line classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'?

Comment: I am really confused with your settings.gradle .It looks like build.gradle and you have to include the project in settings.gradle and compile in build.gradle

Comment: i tryed the second suggest and it writes: "Specify location of the Gradle or android eclipse project". maybe that's because i moved from eclipse to android studio?

Comment: which means the library you are trying to import is not a studio project .it's missing gradle. try this New Module->Andoid library->give the name of your sdk->copy the package and paste it in java of new library.